# Connection using java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

to connect to the server using RMI I use the below code.. works perfectly.

However as you can see below every time a button is pressed I have to re connect and keep doing so with every button.. is there a way to connect once and keep using it through out the class??

For example instead of keep writing that same code to connect again and again.. is there a way to do it once?.. so i can make the program more efficient. Thanks in advance.

```
 if ( evt.getSource() == button1) 
    {
        try {           
            Remote kay = Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/hey");
            Hey u = (Hey) kay;  
            u.canSaw(que);              
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("fail");
            }

    }

    if ( evt.getSource() == button2) 
    {
        try {

            Remote kay = Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/hey");
            Hey u = (Hey) kay;  
            u.canSaw(see);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("failed");
            }


    }
```

Comment: Have you considered making `kay` a member variable in the class that contains this code, and then just leaving out the lookups?

Answer (score 0):

RMI connections are implicit. You can't manage them yourself.

But you don't have to keep looking up the same remote object. Look it up once, and save the result.

You shouldn't be doing any of this on the event thread.